# What is the Hebrew equivalent term for ’Logos’ and where is this Hebrew equivalent term used in the Old Testament?

Tags: word-study

John 1:1-2

> <sup>**1**</sup> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. <sup>**2**</sup> The same was in the beginning with God.

What is the Hebrew equivalent term for ’Logos’ and where is this Hebrew equivalent term used in the Old Testament?

Comment: דָּבָר (*davar*). Occurrences in the OT, see [here](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h1697/kjv/wlc/0-1/).

Comment: Have a look at the 'oracle', the inner sanctum of Solomon's temple. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 3):

In the Hebrew New Testament translations of Franz Julius Delitzsch and of the Bible Society of Israel have
בְּרֵאשִׁית הָיָה הַדָּבָר
.  However, the Hebrew equivalent of ὁ λόγος in John 1 is debated. Here is how it is used in the Septuagint (LXX).

**Figure 1.** The Hebrew words λόγος translates in the LXX (generated with Logos Bible Software)

[image]

דָּבָר
has a broader meaning, including matter and thing, which aren't meanings for  λόγος. The word λόγος does have the meaning of statement and message as well as word.

**Figure 2.** Senses of דָּבָר as used in the Tanakh

[image]

**Conclusion**: When one compares John's prolegomena with Genesis 1, λόγος makes a connection with "God said."  Both verb forms λέγω and דָּבַר have the meaning *speak*.  God speaking creation into existence implied God thinking, thus intelligence (see [What does “God said” mean in Gen. 1:3,6,9,11,14,20,24,26?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/54018/what-does-god-said-mean-in-gen-13-6-9-11-14-20-24-26/54099#54099)).  Thus, many connect λόγος with its meaning of *reason*, with out Greek philosophers used the term.

**Occurrences in the Old Testament**

דָּבָר occurs 1440 times in the Tanakh

λόγος occurs 1180 times in the LXX

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the word logos is described in the New Testament.

> ◄ 3056. logos ►
> Strong's Concordance
> logos: a word (as embodying an idea), a statement, a speech
> Original Word: λόγος, ου, ὁ

Transliteration: logos

> Definition: a word (as embodying an idea), a statement, a speech
> Usage: a word, speech, divine utterance, analogy.

HELPS Word-studies
3056 lógos (from 3004 /légō, "speaking to a conclusion") – a word, being the expression of a thought; a saying. 3056 /lógos ("word") is preeminently used of Christ (Jn 1:1), expressing the thoughts of the Father through the Spirit.

Here is the equivalent of the word in the Old Testament .

Here is the word DABAR defined.
1697. dabar ►

> I. singular speech, discourse, saying, word, as the sum of that which is spoken:

In summary, both words, mean to sum up some form of communication.  It usually embodies a plan, an action, and an ending to that plan or action contained, in a word.

Answer (score 1):

The closest Hebrew equivalent to the Greek λόγος (logos) is probably דָבָר (davar).  Its meaning is quite varied - see https://biblehub.com/hebrew/1697.htm

It occurs over 1440 times in the OT, eg, Gen 1:11, 12:17, 15:1, etc.  See https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_1697.htm

Comment: . . . . .. . 'Probably' ?

Answer (score 0):

The logos **pervades** the OT.
This is a given in John's prologue.

> There was a man sent from God whose name was John. He came as a witness to testify concerning that light, so that through him all might believe. He himself was not the light; he came only as a witness to the light.
>
> The true light that gives light to everyone **was coming** into the world.
>
> John 1:6-8,9 NIV

In other words, all that preceded John, and John himself, was leading toward, a manifestation of light.
Until then, between Eden and John, there had been an idea of that manifestation. The logos or idea.
That manifestation was to be in the form of a man, but John wasn't that man. That man was at that time unknown.

> "... among you stands one ***you do not know***. He is the one who **comes after me**, the straps of whose sandals I am not worthy to untie.”
>
> John 1:26-27 NIV

John elaborates as to the identity of this light that manifested after him :

> The Word (logos) became flesh and made his dwelling among us. We have seen his glory, the glory of the one and only Son, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth.
>
> (John testified concerning him. He cried out, saying, “*This is the one I spoke about when I said*, ‘**He who comes after me** *has surpassed me because he was before* (πρῶτός) *me*.’”)
>
> For the law was given through Moses; grace and truth came through Jesus Christ.
>
> John 1:14,15,17 NIV

That "before me" (πρῶτός) used in the sense of hierarchy :

> “Anyone who wants to be first (πρῶτος) must be the very last, and the servant of all.”
>
> Mark 9:35 NIV

> ... whoever wants to be first (πρῶτος) must be slave of all.
>
> Mark 10:44 NIV

A respectful translation :

> (John beareth witness concerning him, and hath cried aloud, saying––the same, was he that said––He who, **after me**, **was coming**, before me, hath advanced; **because, my Chief, was he**.)
>
> John 1:15 Rotherham

Not πρῶτός in the chronological sense.  Obviously.

This idea, or promise of a redeemer, who was to be elevated above all others, was given, in the beginning :

> And I will put enmity
> between you and the woman,
> and between your offspring and hers;
> **he will crush your head**,
> and you will strike his heel.”
>
> Genesis 3:15 NIV

The promise of a descendent of Adam, but born of a woman, that would crush serpent thinking. As Jesus explains to Nicodemus :

> Just as Moses lifted up the snake in the wilderness, so the Son of Man must be lifted up ...
>
> John 3:14 NIV

This promise, given in the garden, covenanted with blood :

> The Lord God made *garments of skin* for Adam and his wife and clothed them.
>
> Genesis 3:21 NIV

Jesus thus referred to in type as :

> ... the Lamb who was slain *from the creation of the world*.
>
> Revelation 13:8 NIV

This promise given in Eden, memorialized by their firstborn Abel.
This promise repeated in Abraham :

> Abraham answered, “***God himself will provide the lamb*** for the burnt offering, my son.”
>
> Abraham looked up and there in a thicket he saw a ram caught by its horns. He went over and took the ram and sacrificed it as a burnt offering instead of his son. So Abraham called that place The Lord **Will Provide**.
>
> Genesis 22:8,13-14 NIV

And in kind to David :

> **I will be his father**, and **he will be my son**.
>
> 2 Samuel 7:14 NIV

A future descendent of Adam and Eve, and Abraham and David, but born only of a woman, for god will be his father, that through his obedience, in crushing serpent thinking, would open a door to *redemption from the curse of death pronounced **in the beginning***.

This foreknowledge of god forming the opening of John's prologue :

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. He was with God in the beginning.
>
> The light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.
>
> John 1:1,5 NIV

That light, in the beginning, being of course the guiding light, against the darkness, of **the first four days**.
That light emanating from the father and then  working through the prophets :

> We also have the prophetic message as something completely reliable, and you will do well to pay attention to it, as to a light shining in a dark place ...
>
> 2 Peter 1:19 NIV

It's not until the **fourth day** that we see the manifestation of a corresponding physical source.

> In the beginning ...
>
> And God said, “Let there be light,” and there was light. God saw that the light was good, and ***he separated** the light from the darkness*. And there was evening, and there was morning—the first day.
>
> And God said, “Let there be lights in the vault of the sky to separate the day from the night, and **let them serve as signs** to mark sacred times, and days and years, and **let them be lights** in the vault of the sky *to give light on the earth*.” And it was so. God set them in the vault of the sky *to give light on the earth, **to govern the day and the night, and to separate light from darkness***. And God saw that it was good. And there was evening, and there was morning—the fourth day.
>
> Genesis 1:1,3-4,5,14-15,17-19

Four days of creation, the light being manifest from deity, then **on the fourth day**, *a physical manifestation of a source*.
Four thousand years from Adam to Messiah.

> A thousand years in your sight
> are like a day that has just gone by,
> or like a watch in the night.
>
> Psalm 90:4 NIV

And of course the subject of the opening of John's prologue, being an idea, a thing, **the logos**, we should expect where pronouns are concerned, to see "it" not "he" or "him".
Sadly we have to go back 400 years to get that kind of neutral transparency :

> **Geneva Bible of 1587**
> This same was in the beginning with God.
> All things were made by it, and without it was made nothing that was made.
> In it was life, and that life was the light of men.
> And that light shineth in the darkenesse, and the darkenesse comprehended it not.
>
> **Bishops' Bible of 1568**
> The same was in the begynnyng with God.
> All thynges were made by it: and without it, was made nothyng that was made.
> In it was lyfe, and the lyfe was the lyght of men,
> And the lyght shyneth in darkenesse: and the darknesse comprehended it not.
>
> **Coverdale Bible of 1535**
> The same was in the begynnynge wt God.
> All thinges were made by the same, and without the same was made nothinge that was made.
> In him was the life, and the life was the light of men:
> and the light shyneth in the darknesse, and the darknesse comprehended it not.
>
> **Tyndale Bible of 1526**
> The same was in the beginnynge with God.
> All thinges were made by it and with out it was made nothinge that was made.
> In it was lyfe and the lyfe was ye lyght of men
> and the lyght shyneth in the darcknes but the darcknes comprehended it not.

Even amongst the apostasy, with the exception of one particular pronoun, all true to John's narrative, that the subject is the logos, **a thing**, particularly, an idea.
Modern translations catering to the drooling aficionados of the the logos not being an idea, but rather Jesus himself, *a perspective opposed* to John's deliberate progression. How popular would those translations be, if they didn't capitalise the "word" or write "he" or "him" every chance they get. An embarrassment. Forget about responsibility, that's about popularity.

> This is the verdict: Light has come into the world, but people loved darkness instead of light ...
>
> John 3:19 NIV

John labours the progression and chooses his words carefully.
First the logos or idea, that idea being a promise given in the beginning, not a man, rather **the promise of** a man, **then** John, **then** the man.

**This promise** being the light of the world, illuminated by the father, and then 4000 years after, manifest in the man Jesus.
This idea or logos not being merely a topic in scripture, but the purpose and function of elohim themselves.

> Are not all angels ministering spirits sent to serve those who will inherit salvation?
>
> Hebrews 1:14 NIV

It is in this sense John writes :

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.
>
> John 1:1 NIV

*The purpose and function of elohim being to guide the creation toward **the manifestation of the character of deity in a man***.

Answer (score 0):

The word/dabar in Isaiah 55;10-11 is similar to the word/logos in John. Rain/dabar/word is a gift sent by God, it brings life, the word is sent, the word /rain will not return to God empty, returns to God when its purpose is accomplished. Now consider the similarities in John 8:23 I am from above, the Father sent the son so those who will believe will have life John 3:16. Jesus did the work the God sent him to do, John 17:4, Jesus ascended to the Father, John 20:17.

However, there is no God the word or a logos Creator in the Old Testament or even in the New Testament, if that is the Old Testament equivalent term that this question is looking for. The phrase "the word of the LORD" appears hundreds of times in the Old Testament, but it does not say nor hint that the word is a distinct person equal to YHWH. That is why Jesus said that his Father is greater than all, John 10:29, Jesus included, John 14:28. Psalm 33:6 says the heavens were created by YHWH's word. That is why Jesus ascribed creation to his God and not to himself, Mark 13:19.

God's desire is that we may know Him, the only true God, John 17:3, thus, the significance of his words. Communication between God and man are either heard or written through His word. Hence , we go the bible to look for the equivalent term. The hebrew word for "word" is dabar. In Psalm 107:20. we read,

Psalm 107:20 Literal Standard Version

He sends His word and heals them, | And delivers [them] from their destructions.

In John 3:16, God sent his only begotten to save those who believe.

Sticking strictly to what the bible say, there is no dabar/logos/word as a person in the OT. There is also no God the word or God the son in the OT and the rest of the bible if that is how some interpret the logos of John.